# Find $P(|x - 0.99|<0.01)$ in normal distribution in a sample

Tags: probability, statistics

> The content in litres of bottled water follows a normal distribution
>   with average 0.99 and standard deviation of 0.02.
>
> b) Determine the size of the sample so that the probability that the
>   difference between the average of the sample and the average of the
>   population doesn't exceed 0.01 is at least 0.95.

Basically I am trying to do this in a different way:
[image]

$$P(-0.01 < X < 1) = 0.95 \Leftrightarrow \\
P(0.98 < X < 1) = 0.95 \\
A = P(0.98 < X) \\
B= P(X <1)\\
P(A\cap B ) =P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B) \Leftrightarrow \\
0.95 = \phi(-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2})+\phi(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2})-1 \Leftrightarrow \\
0.95 = 1-2\phi(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2})-1$$

What went wrong?

EDIT: Honestly what I don't understand about my professor's solution is how he got from the left side of line 4 to the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your computation of $P(A)$: $P(A)=1-\Phi(-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2})$. Plugging that in, you get:

$$P(A\cap B ) =P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B) \Leftrightarrow \\
0.95 = 1-\Phi(-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2})+\Phi(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2})-1 \Leftrightarrow \\
0.95 = \Phi(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}) - \Phi(-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2})$$
which is what is on line 4.

Comment: Right, silly mistake. Thanks.

Comment: @Segmentationfault drawing a cdf and highlighting the area left of $\sqrt{n}/2$ and left of $-\sqrt{n}/2$ is another way to understand line 4

Comment: I haven't delved much into Mathematica yet. I will definetly try when I do.

Comment: @Segmentationfault a sketch on paper suffices in this case :)

Comment: I did that then. I understand what you mean. I just forgot I had that 1- there.

Comment: @Segmentationfault alrighty then. Could you mark this question as answered for the other users?

Comment: Sure, sorry. It said I had to wait and meanwhile I had forgotten.